# Okular stretched aspect ratio in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, pdf, okular

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 okular went crazy and renders every pdf in a strange manner. Please see the image for an example. I tried reinstalling, purging, allowing for newer sources and installing again but nothing works. Does anyone know or have an idea on how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and even purging a package does not remove its user specific configuration files. Seeing how your problem persists across reinstalls it might be a good idea to reset your configuration to the defaults.

One way to do this is by renaming the existing configuration files and directories. In case of Okular these would be:

```
~/.kde/share/apps/okular
~/.kde/share/config/okularpartrc
~/.kde/share/config/okularrc
```

You could rename them to `okular_backup`, etc.

Try to start Okular now and see if anything changed. If you are still facing the same issue you are likely dealing with a bug and should probably report it to [KDE's bug tracker](https://bugs.kde.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did think purge would remove user configuration. Unfortunately nothing changed after I renamed the files/folders. Well the configuration was reset but the display problem is still there. I'll see about reporting it.

Comment: I'm getting the same bug with a fresh installation so I guess it's confirmed. It just puzzles me that there are no more hits for this when I google it.